# Analysis of a multivariable function with arguments over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^m$ be

$$f(x, \vec{t}) = \frac{xm}{\sum_{j = 1}^mt_j}$$

Finding $\partial f/\partial x$ is simple, but I don't understand how to deal with $\partial f/\partial \vec{t}$, since $\vec{t}$ is an $m$-dimensional vector. What is tha gradient of this function? How does one treat vectorial arguments in this context?

Thanks.

Comment: It is also an $m$ - dimensional vector, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\vec t}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t_1}&\cdots&\frac{\partial f}{\partial t_m}\end{bmatrix}$$ Let $f_x(t):=f(x,t).$ Then $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\vec t}"="\operatorname{grad}f_x$$